# access store data from one slice to another slice in redux toolkit to pass custom param in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Profile Slice:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { IMAGE_API, ACCESS_KEY } from "../../app/utils/constant";

export const getImages = createAsyncThunk('images', async () => {
  return fetch(`${IMAGE_API + ACCESS_KEY}`).then((res) =>
    res.json()
  )
})
console.log(IMAGE_API + ACCESS_KEY);

const ProfilePicSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'imageList',
  initialState: {
    images: [],
    loading: false,
  },
  extraReducers:  (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getImages.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    })
    builder.addCase(getImages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.images.push(action.payload);
      console.log(action.payload)
    })
    builder.addCase(getImages.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    })
  }
});

export default ProfilePicSlice.reducer
```

Form Slice:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = []

const UserSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    }
  }
});

export const {addUser} = UserSlice.actions;
export default UserSlice.reducer;
```

I want to add custom param in API URL in asyncThunk '${IMAGE_API + 'custom param' + ACCESS_KEY}

custom param should come from form slice data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redux-toolkit` async thunks are able to access the `ThunkAPI`, which includes a function to get the current redux state object, it is the second argument passed to the thunk callback. From here you can select the state value you need.

See [PayloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator).

Example:

```
export const getImages = createAsyncThunk(
  'imageList /images',
  (_, { getState }) => {
    const store = getState();

    const param = state.users./* access into state to get property */;

    return fetch(`${IMAGE_API}${param}${ACCESS_KEY}`)
      .then((res) => res.json());
  }
);
```